# Sending a text string from android to a textfield on a website?

Tags: android

I'm trying to paste a string from my application to a website.

My application look as following. One `EditText` and one `Button`. My button opens a website with an open text box.

```
<input name="FreeTextBox" type="text" id="FreeTextBox" style="width:64px;">
```

this is the id of the textbox on the website if it helps.

my application's `EditText` id is et2 which is then the variable `klass` in java.
`klassen = klass.getText().toString();` the `klass` variable is then made into a string `klassen`

When I click my `Button` I open a website and then I want my application to automaticlly to enter what ever i wrote in my `EditText` into the `FreeTextBox` on the website.

Please give me advice on how to do this. This is my first application so I could really use some help. If possible could you give me a working example of this with my variables, I really suck at this.

Thanks in advance!